# How to make two same size UIViews within a parent container programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

How do I make two uiviews the same size regardless of screen size by programmatically setting constraints?

I know how to do make the constraints on storyboard but I am trying to learn to also do it programmatically.

Below is an example of my storyboard constraints

[image]

Here is my attempt in viewwilllayoutsubview()

```
    view.addSubview(topView)
    view.addSubview(bottomView)

    topView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    topView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    topView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    topView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.size.height / 2).isActive = true

    bottomView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    bottomView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    bottomView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    bottomView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: Use a vertical `UIStackView` set to fill equally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work well but you need to put it inside `viewDidLoad` with `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` set to `false` for every view

```
topView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
bottomView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

     topView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor) ,
     topView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor) ,
     topView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
     topView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.size.height / 2),

     bottomView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.bottomAnchor),
     bottomView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
     bottomView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
     bottomView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
])
```

Also you can replace this

```
topView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.size.height / 2)
```

with

```
topView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomView.heightAnchor)
```